# Run a phantom.js file on Heroku regularly

Tags: heroku, scheduled-tasks, phantomjs

I've uploaded a single file to Heroku that crawls a website and responds the edited content in JSON format on an http request. I now want to update the content regularly so the content stays up to date. I tried using the Heroku Scheduler however I am failing to schedule the process so that it runs correctly.

I have specified the following process in the Heroku Scheduler:

```
run phantomjs phantom.js      //Using 1X Dyno, every hour.
//phantom.js is the file that contains my source code and that runs the server.
```

However if I enter

```
heroku ps
```

into the terminal, I only see one web dyne running and no scheduler task. Also if I type

```
heroku logs --ps scheduler.1
```

as described in the Scheduler documentation, there is no output.

---

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: I only had to write

```
phantomjs phantom.js
```

in order to get it working. It was the "run" that made the expression invalid

Answer (score 0):

For what it sounds like you want to accomplish, you need to be constantly running

1 Web Dyno
1 Background Worker

When your scheduled task executes, it will be run by the background worker. Which, since you haven't provisioned it, isn't executing.